# fopen retornando NULL

Tags: c, null, fopen

Boa noite, estou com um problema na função fopen dentro de uma sub-rotina. Esta retornando `NULL`. Não consegui identificar o erro pois ainda sou iniciante, se alguém puder me auxiliar. Obs: declarei `FILE *arq` em escopo global, tentei mudá-lo para dentro da main e também da função `rcaracter()`, mas mesmo assim continua retornando `NULL` e caindo no IF da mensagem de erro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rcaracter();
void rpalavra();

FILE *arq;

int main(void)
{
    int i,opt;
    char palavra[30];
    
    
    do  
    {
        printf("Programa:Arquivo\n");
        printf("-Menu-\n");
        printf("[1]-Arquivo Caracter\n");
        printf("[2]-Arquivo Palavra\n");
        printf("[3]-Sair\n");
        printf("Opção:");
        scanf("%d", &opt);
        system("cls");
    
    
        switch (opt)
        {
            case 1:
                rcaracter();        
            break;  
        
            case 2:
            
            break;
        }
    
    }while(opt != 3);

}

void rcaracter()
{
    char caracter;

        arq = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r+");
        if(arq == NULL) 
        {
            printf("Falha na abertura\n");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Digite o caracter:");
            scanf("%c", caracter);
            fflush(stdin);
            system("cls");
            
            while (caracter != 'f')
            {
                fputc(caracter, arq);    
                if (ferror(arq))        
                {
                    printf("Falha na gravação\n");
                    system("pause");
                    system("cls");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Sucesso!");
                }
                printf("Digite outro caracter ou 'f' para sair:");
                scanf("%c", caracter);  
            }
        }
        fclose(arq);        
}
```

Comment: pode explicar melhor o que está tentando fazer e talvez postar um conteúdo para seu arquivo de teste e a saída esperada?

Comment: Difícil responder sem saber exatamente qual é o erro. Para descobrir o erro, inclua o *header* `errno.h`, e no if que está retornando NULL, mude o print da mensagem para `printf("Falha na abertura: %s\n", strerror(errno));`. Assim, você poderá editar a pergunta e incluir a mensagem, o que talvez o ajude a obter uma resposta.

Comment: Bom dia arfneto e Gomiero. Gostaria de informar-lhes que descobri o problema ("o porque do erro"), inclui o errno.h indicado pelo amigo Gomiero e entendi que o problema era relacionado a diretório, logo então descobri que estava utilizando como parâmetro do 'modo de abertura' do fopen, um "especificador" que só realiza a abertura do arquivo e não a criação do mesmo (r+), troquei para (w+) e funcionou. Sei que o problema é simples e foi uma falta de atenção, mas como estou iniciando acabo cometendo estes deslizes as vezes. Peço desculpas e agradeço pelas valiosas informações.

Answer (score 0):

**@Ramiro**   creio que o eerro no seu código seja por erro de syntaxe , pois ficou faltando o caractere & nos scanf's , e assim o compilador finaliza a execução do programa , e outra coisa é que se você usar o "w+' ou "w" o arquivo será criado todas as vezes que você compilar o código , sim , mas , esse mesmo arquivo que foi criado , então ele será criado novamente e também resetado  deletando todos os dados que já estiverem sido gravados nele , que assim se perderão , então melhor usar o tipo "a" de append , que abre o arquivo para leitura e também pode gravar dados a partir do final dele , mantendo o seu conteúdo , e então seu código com algumas modificações poderia ser assim  :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define cls system("cls");
#define getch() _getch()
int rcaracter();
int rpalavra ();
int main( void )
{
    int i,opt;
    char palavra[30];
    do
    {
        printf("\n\t  Programa : Arquivo    \n\
                \r\t    --- Menu ---        \n\
                \r\t[ 1 ] - Arquivo Caracter\n\
                \r\t[ 2 ] - Arquivo Palavra \n\
                \r\t[ 3 ] - Sair            \n\
                \r\t        Opção : "        );
        scanf("%d", &opt);
        cls
        switch ( opt )
        {
        case 1:
            rcaracter();
            break;
        case 2:
            rpalavra();
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            printf("opcao invaLida !\n");;;;;
        }
    }while( opt != 3 );
    return 0;
}
int rcaracter()
{
    char caracter;
    FILE* arq;                                /// FILE é um ponteiro qq e mais seguro aqui dentro da fun
    /// arq = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r+");     /// r de read   lêlê e Gravaa no iniciô do Arquivu !
    arq = fopen("arquivo.txt", "a");          /// a de Append lêlê e Gravaa no FinAu  do Arquivu !
                                              /// tenta abrir o arquivo
    if(arq == NULL)                           /// se o arquivo nao existir
    {
        printf("Falha na abertura\n");        /// escreve msg de erro inf o usuario disso
        printf("esse Arquivo ainda nao existe , e serah criado AgoRa ! . . .\n   Tecle\n");
        arq = fopen("arquivo.txt","w");       /// cria abre e reseta  o arquivo para gravar
                                              /// no inicio dele
        getch();                              /// espera ethernamente até clicar em algum botao
        cls                                   /// Macro
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Digite o caracter -: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        setbuf(stdin,NULL);                    /// limpar o buffer antes de scanf
                                               /// scanf tem problemas em ler cractere
        scanf("%c", & caracter);               /// Faltou o & de endereço da variavel
                                               /// ele finaliza a execução
        cls                                    /// MAcro
        while ( caracter != 'f' )              /// enQuanto nao digitar   f
        {
            fputc(caracter, arq);              /// gravar um caractere no arquivo txt
            if ( ferror ( arq ) )              /// se houver erro na gravação
            {
                printf("Falha na gravação\n"); /// mostra msg
                getch();                       /// espera até ehernamente até pressionar alguma tecla
                cls                            /// uma MaCro para LimparAtela
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Sucesso . . . !\n    ");/// escreve msg para o usuario
            }
            printf("Digite outro caracter ou   'f'   para sair --: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            setbuf(stdin,NULL);
            scanf("%c", & caracter);            /// faltou o & , termina a execução sem passar por fclose
                                                /// que faz efetivamente a validação de gracacao
        }
    }
    fclose( arq );                              /// validar a gravacao dos dados no arquivo
    return 0;                                   /// retorna para o windows uma msg q pode ser usada
                                                /// em outro programa
}
int rpalavra()
{
    printf("estah no rpalavra . . . !\n");
    getch();
}
```